# Why am I getting SQL Error 42x80?

Tags: sql, database, derby

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id INT NOT NULL generated always AS identity(start WITH 1, increment BY 1) CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY
    ,cFirstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,cLastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,cPhone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,cstreet VARCHAR(50)
    ,czipcode VARCHAR(5)
    ,CONSTRAINT customers_uk01 UNIQUE (
        cFirstname
        ,cLastname
        ,cPhone
        )
    );

INSERT INTO customer (
    cFirstname
    ,cLastname
    ,cPhone
    ,cstreet
    ,czipcode
    )
VALUES (
    'Dave'
    ,'Brown'
    ,'562-982-8696'
    ,'123 Lakewood Blvd. Long Beach'
    ,'90080'
    )
    ,(
    'Rachel'
    ,'Burris'
    ,'213-543-2211'
    ,'54 218th St. Torrance'
    ,'90210'
    )
    ,(
    'Tom'
    ,'Jewett'
    ,'714-555-1212'
    ,'10200 Slater'
    ,'92708'
    )
    ,(
    'Alvero'
    ,'Monge'
    ,'562-111-1234'
    ,'314159 Pi St. Long Beach'
    ,'90814'
    ),);
```

I'm getting the error at the line "insert into customer".

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X80] VALUES clause must
>   contain at least one element. Empty elements are not allowed.

What is causing the error?

Comment: The extra comma in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `,)` at the end of your query:

[image]